# Spring Boot - use H2 for unit testing AND for quick development (with a Spring profile)

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, spring-test

How can I use H2 both for the normal Unit Testing AND during (the first part of) development? I could start the application with a specific Spring Profile so that the application-h2.properties would be selected.

I have two projects: for simplicity I used exactly the same POM files.

When I create a simple Spring Boot Application -- immediately inserting/reading db stuff, then all works fine.

Important dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
</dependency>
```

When I have an Angular / Spring Boot application, again with the same Maven dependencies, thus with much web stuff, then I keep on getting this error:

> IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver

**UPDATE**: When looking for the maven dependency tree, in both projects I get the dependency:

```
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.197:compile
```

**UPDATE**: Even when I put the h2 dependency with scope 'runtime', unit testing still works with h2 AND the driver is not found

```
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.197:runtime
```

Comment: Just a general comment, IMO using an in memory DB for unit testing is a bad idea it makes your unit tests fragile.  Depending on what pipeline you are doing in your CI/CD process the unit testing which depends on you being able to spin up an in-memory DB may fail.  I would suggest instead that you leverage Mockito to mock your DB for unit testing.  If you want an in memory DB for integration testing I would agree with that.

I suggest finding out what jar the class `org.h2.Driver` exists in.  Then doing a mvn dependency tree print out and attaching the results.